# NPM Package Install Affected Dependencies List

Tags: npm, installation, dry-run

This is probably a total noob question about npm, but I'm wondering how I can extract the dependencies that would be installed when doing an install, for instance with dry-run.

The reasoning is that I want to know which packages are going to be installed, before actually performing the install.

In this way I can make sure that one particular package is avoided, should I want to define it so.

Comment: You can execute a script before to install that verify your dependencies. Look to this documentation https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could Examine a package's dependency graph before you install it.
By making installing rnp-remote-ls: https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-remote-ls

First you install it the module gloablly:

```
npm install -g npm-remote-ls
```

Second you run:

```
npm-remote-ls <packagename>
```

Comment: True, but then I want to diff it with the local dep tree. So I could get smth like:
New packages to be installed: a-v1, b-v2, c-v1
Local packages to be updated: e-v1->e-v3

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this,

Add a custom "install" script in your `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "custominstall",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "custom-install": "node custom-install"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  }
}
```

Create `custom-install.js` in your root directory.

```
const { execSync } = require('child_process');

const packageJson = require('./package.json');

if (!packageJson.devDependencies.hasOwnProperty('nodemon')) {
    execSync(
        'npm install',
        {
            stdio: [
                0,
                1,
                2
            ]
        }
    );
} else {
    throw new Error('nodemon package should not be used in this project!');
}
```

This example code checks if `nodemon` package has been used as `devDependency`. Throws an error if it's used. Runs `npm install` and shows the command's output to you if it is not used.

You can customize it for your needs.

Use it like

```
npm run custom-install
```

Comment: Cool, I guess that would work for this scenario. I am surprised that there isn't something that can tell me which packages will be upgraded/installed, in a npm install -impact -dry-run kind of way. npm has the calculate the new dependency tree, why can't we see/diff it?